# php regex replace local relative pathways

Tags: php, regex

I have multiple relative links that are included in a string. However I want too have all the links replace with a simple `javascript:alert("Sorry You Cannot Do That.")` and I do not want any absolute pathways such as `http://google.com` to change only the relative pathways such as `/conf/bin.html`.

Here is an example code snippet:

```
$pattern = "/<a(.*) href='\/(.*)'(.*)>reply</a>/";
$string = "<a target='_blank' href='/conf/bin?post=5760627b29ba0' name='bin' id='bin' class='bin' title='Hide From Feed'></a>
wow
<a target='_blank' href='/conf/bin?post=5760627b29ba0' name='bin' id='bin' class='bin' title='Hide From Feed'></a> wow";
while (preg_match($pattern, $string)){

$string = preg_replace($pattern, "<tr><td align='right'><a href='javascript:alert(" . chr(34) . "Sorry You Cannot Do That" . chr(34) . ")' style='text-decoration:none;'>reply</a>", $string);
}
```

And I want the string to end up as:

```
$string = "<a target='_blank' href='javascript:alert(" . chr(34) . "Sorry You Cannot Do That" . chr(34) . ")' name='bin' id='bin' class='bin' title='Hide From Feed'></a>
wow
<a target='_blank' href='javascript:alert(" . chr(34) . "Sorry You Cannot Do That" . chr(34) . ")' name='bin' id='bin' class='bin' title='Hide From Feed'></a> wow";
```

Can anyone help.
Thanks

Comment: I'd use a parser for this.

Comment: @chris85 could you show me how?

Comment: What is the expected behavior of an absolute URL to your domain, leave it as is?

Comment: absolute URL = http://google.com

Comment: relative = /index.php

Comment: no that does not matter

Comment: Okay, I think answer should now work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `domdocument` to parse the HTML and then a regex to validate the URL.

```
    $string = "<a target='_blank' href='/conf/bin?post=5760627b29ba0' name='bin' id='bin' class='bin' title='Hide From Feed'></a>
wow
<a target='_blank' href='/conf/bin?post=5760627b29ba0' name='bin' id='bin' class='bin' title='Hide From Feed'></a> wow
<a target='_blank' href='http://www.google.com/conf/bin?post=5760627b29ba0' name='bin' id='bin' class='bin' title='Hide From Feed'></a>";
$string .= '<script type="text/javascript">function send_alert(){ alert("Sorry You Cannot Do That.");}</script>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($string);
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    if(preg_match('~^(?!https?://)~', $link->getAttribute('href'))) {
        $link->setAttribute('href', 'javascript:send_alert();');
    }
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/595820
Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/mP2gC8/1

or an alternative quoted version:

```
$string = "<a target='_blank' href='/conf/bin?post=5760627b29ba0' name='bin' id='bin' class='bin' title='Hide From Feed'></a>
wow
<a target='_blank' href='/conf/bin?post=5760627b29ba0' name='bin' id='bin' class='bin' title='Hide From Feed'></a> wow
<a target='_blank' href='http://www.google.com/conf/bin?post=5760627b29ba0' name='bin' id='bin' class='bin' title='Hide From Feed'></a>";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($string);
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    if(preg_match('~^(?!https?://)~', $link->getAttribute('href'))) {
        $link->setAttribute('href', 'javascript:alert(decodeURIComponent(\'Sorry You Cannot Do That.\'));');
    }
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Demo: https://eval.in/595836

Answer (score 1):

You can use DOMDocument combined with XPath, and fetch all such tags with an XPath query:

```xml
//a[starts-with(@href, '/') and text()='reply']
```

As in your question this tests for `a`-tags that:

- have an `href` value that is not an "absolute" path (e.g. not `http://google.com`, but `abc/def/ghi.php` or `/abc/x.php`), and
- have as tag-content `reply`.

For the first test you could just test for the absence of the colon (`:`).

Note that if you replace the `href` value with javascript, you should also remove the `target` property, as that would unnecessarily open a new browser window.

Here is the code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($string);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
foreach($xpath->query("//a[not(contains(@href, ':')) and text()='reply']") as $link) {
    $link->setAttribute('href', 'javascript:alert("Sorry You Cannot Do That");');
    // remove any target attribute
    $link->removeAttribute('target');
}
// remove the stuff that DOMDocument has added:
echo preg_replace("/^.*\<BODY>(.*)<\/BODY><\/HTML>$/is", "$1", $doc->saveHTML());
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/596994)

Note how you can build XPath queries with `and`, `or`, `not()`, `contains()`, ...etc.

Comment: Is it possible for it to change all relative/local paths

Comment: You could check for the absence of the protocol (like `http://`) with this xpath: `//a[not(contains(@href, ':')) and text()='reply']`. I added that to my answer. You can make more complex expressions as needed with `and`, `or`, `not()`, ...etc.

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.g. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/
With this library you can find all 'a' tag:

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($string);

$link = $html->find('a');
```

When you find all 'a' elements then you can replace some part of it
Check "How to modify HTML elements" tab e.g

```
$link = $html->find('a')->href = 'new value of href'
```